# Firebase Config Error: Invalid argument, must be in key=val format

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When I issue the command `firebase functions:config:get`, I get the following:

```
{
  "gmail": {
    "email": "name@example.com",
    "password": "123ABc_"
  }
}
```

Then I run `firebase functions:config:set gmail.email = "name@example.com" gmail.password = "new_password"`, I get the following:

```
Error: Invalid argument gmail.email, must be in key=val format
```

Why? According to [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), it seems like nothing wrong with my syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should remove the spaces, as follows:

```
firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="name@example.com"
```

In other words, it should be `key=val` and not `key = val`